# Moving complete rows in a QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have a tab which contains a `QtableView` and few buttons like "MOVE UP" and "MOVE DOWN". So on "MOVE UP" button press I have to move the entire row of `QTableView` one step up and the bring the adjacent one, one step down. I want to achieve this without creating complete model again since it may take time to construct the whole model again. Instead I just want to MOVE UP the selected row in the view.
Please let me know the simplest way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What model class are you using?

Comment: I am using QStandardItemModel

Comment: Then you don't need to construct all data again. You only need to swap 2 rows. Why can't you do that? What have you tried?

Comment: There is no method to directly Swap to rows.I was thinking of two approach one is Setting the sort role and sorting and other was to use SetItem and TakeRow methods (but i am not sure if either of them will work)

Comment: You can use `takeItem()` to take all item from both rows and store them in temporary variables. After that you can use `setItem()` to insert items in the new positions. It this acceptable?

Comment: I think a working solution will be to use setSortRole and then call Sort

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any knowledge of the model to do any of this, and most of the commenters are quite mistaken with any mention of the model at all.

You simply need to obtain the view's `verticalHeader`, and do a section swap of the item you want with the one above it. You might need to tell the `verticalHeader` to allow for reordering `setMovable(true)`

One of the main tenants QT and ModelView programming is to understand and appreciate the separation of manipulating a model from manipulating a view of the model.

Answer (score 0):

I made the move up and down functions and this is what my `.cpp` contains

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

model = new QStandardItemModel(4,2,this);
for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
        {
            QModelIndex index
                    = model->index(row,col,QModelIndex());
            // 0 for all data
            model->setData(index,row);
        }
    }
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_upPushButton_clicked()
{
    if(ui->tableView->currentIndex().row()<=0)
    {
        return;
    }
    QList<QStandardItem *> list = model->takeRow(ui->tableView->currentIndex().row());
    model->insertRow(ui->tableView->currentIndex().row(),list);
}

void Widget::on_downPushButton_clicked()
{

int selectedRow = ui->tableView->currentIndex().row() ;
if(selectedRow == ui->tableView->model()->rowCount()-1)
{
   return;
}
QList<QStandardItem *> list = model->takeRow(ui->tableView->currentIndex().row());
model->insertRow(selectedRow+1,list);
}
```

[This is what the ui looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIJIv.png)